# Github Codespaces - issue with Port Forwarding

Tags: github-codespaces

Github Codespaces (VSCode web version) returns an error [Error msg: Unable to forward localhost - network error] - network error - screenshot attached - neither auto-forwarding nor manual-forwarding is working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOa3L.png)

Followed all the trouble-shooting advice in Github's official documentation found here:
[text](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-port-forwarding-for-github-codespaces)

Comment: Issue identified:
Auto port forwarding issue arises when the 'Australia' region is selected for the codespace.
No such issue evident when the 'US East' region is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Issue identified:
Auto port forwarding issue arises when the 'Australia' region is selected for the codespace.
No such issue evident when the 'US East' region is selected.